# Tracker layout in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="#13CF13" Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="20" CornerRadius="40">
     <Label WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
</Frame>
```

**Currently this is my implementation and I wanted the output to be like that in the image provided. How to implement it using frames? Or any way. Thanks in advance!**

Comment: can you tell a little more , like how many dates can be there , or how many locations list, what is fixed what is dynamic, in short what is your collection like that you aim to convert to this UI

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi. Here is the data. A list of  dates and list of description <{Location, Status, Time}>. This is the date = List<Date, List<Description>>

Comment: Is not necesarily only two descriptions.

Comment: `This is the date = List<Date, List<Description>>`, how many date in the list? If the date's count less than 20, you can put view(contians date) in the scrollview, if the list have lots of count, we should create an custom listview to achieve it.

Comment: Not more than 20 sir, so need for a custom list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**View :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="MainPageXaml"
             x:Class="DummyTestApp.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="White" Title="Tracker Layout">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
            <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1}"
                             BindingContext="{x:Reference MainPageXaml}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0" 
                             BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding TrackerDateDataList}"
                             x:Name="myBoxView">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RelativeLayout x:Name="MainRelLayout" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                                <Frame HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="LightGray" BorderColor="DarkGray" Padding="0"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=30}"
                                   CornerRadius="15" Margin="0,10" HeightRequest="30" 
                                   x:Name="headerFrame">
                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5" Margin="0" Spacing="0">
                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="Yellow" BorderColor="Yellow" WidthRequest="18" HeightRequest="18"
                                           CornerRadius="9" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0" Margin="10,0"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding TrackDate,StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="0,0,30,0"
                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                                <StackLayout RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=26}"
                                         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=headerFrame,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=20}"
                                         BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding DescriptionList}">
                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" Padding="0" Spacing="0">
                                                <Frame BackgroundColor="Yellow" BorderColor="Yellow" WidthRequest="36" HeightRequest="36"
                                                   CornerRadius="18" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0" Margin="10,0"/>
                                                <StackLayout Margin="0" Padding="0" Spacing="2">
                                                    <!-- Add more labels here -->
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Location}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Status}"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                </StackLayout>
                                        <!--
                                            Frame has constant value of 30, then stack has padding 5, then again frame within stack has margin 10 then radius of 18
                                            SO Box constant is 30 + (5/2) + 10 +(18/2) , So around 52.5
                                        -->
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
                <BoxView RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=52.5}"
                         HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference myBoxView}, Path=Height}" 
                         WidthRequest="2" Color="Yellow" Margin="0"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code Behind :**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TrackerDateData> TrackerDateDataList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TrackerDateData>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitilizeTrackerList();
        }

        private void InitilizeTrackerList()
        {
            TrackerDateData tracker1 = new TrackerDateData();
            TrackerDateData tracker2 = new TrackerDateData();
            TrackerDateData tracker3 = new TrackerDateData();
            TrackerDateData tracker4 = new TrackerDateData();

            Description desc1 = new Description();
            Description desc2 = new Description();
            Description desc3 = new Description();

            desc1.Location = "Near Location A";
            desc1.Status = "Dispatched";
            
            desc2.Location = "Near Location B";
            desc2.Status = "Arriving";
            
            desc3.Location = "Near Location C";
            desc3.Status = "Packed";

            tracker1.TrackDate = new DateTime(2020,1,3);
            tracker2.TrackDate = new DateTime(2020,1,2);
            tracker3.TrackDate = new DateTime(2020,1,1);
            tracker4.TrackDate = new DateTime(2019,12,31);

            tracker1.DescriptionList.Add(desc2);
            tracker1.DescriptionList.Add(desc1);
            tracker1.DescriptionList.Add(desc3);
            
            tracker2.DescriptionList.Add(desc1);
            tracker2.DescriptionList.Add(desc3);

            tracker3.DescriptionList.Add(desc3);

            tracker4.DescriptionList.Add(desc3);
            tracker4.DescriptionList.Add(desc2);
            tracker4.DescriptionList.Add(desc2);
            tracker4.DescriptionList.Add(desc1);

            TrackerDateDataList.Add(tracker1);
            TrackerDateDataList.Add(tracker2);
            TrackerDateDataList.Add(tracker3);
            TrackerDateDataList.Add(tracker4);
            TrackerDateDataList.Add(tracker1);
        }
    }

    public class TrackerDateData
    {
        public DateTime TrackDate { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Description> DescriptionList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Description>();
    }
    
    public class Description
    {
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

[Demo to code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDeOB.gif)

Comment: It worked bro, thank you so much. However, I have a question sir. Is it possible that the line will start from the small circle and ends on a small circle? Thanks

Comment: not via the current approach, for that the box view would need to be inside the data templates of both lists(TrackerDateDataList, DescriptionList). It would be difficult and time consuming for me to do that . I've given an idea , you can build on that

Comment: Okay bro. Much appreciated. Thank you so much